# db2 list of stored procedure in a database

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I would like to have the list of stored procedure created in a certain database.
I tried

```
db2 "display procedure MyDb.*"
```

But I get error

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "procedure" was found following "display ".  
Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

In another forum I read that I have to query the table `syscat.procedures`

but if I call

db2 "select * from syscat.procedures"

I get a lot of data I cannot really understand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cut down the details... this will just show you the procedure names:

`SELECT procname FROM syscat.procedures WHERE procschema = 'MYSCHEMA'`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying the syscat.procedures table directly, try using the [SQLProcedures()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=functions-sqlprocedures-get-list-procedure-names) stored procedure instead. There are a number of input parameters you can use to customize your result.